# What is the best approach to perform information extraction from tourist reviews using NLP, DL?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, nlp, text-mining

I am interested in performing some information extraction from tourist reviews about different places.

I have data of 50 different places and around 300-400 reviews about each of them and I would like to get information like: *weather, experience(happy/not happy), costly/cheap, places around, best time to visit, etc.*

**Reviews are like:**

> 1. Mahabaleshwar is a hill station situated nearby Pune. You can reach
>    there by road via Pune. Air connectivity is available up to Pune and
>    from there you can travel by road. Mahabaleshwar is having so many
>    mountain range. Weather is remaining very beautiful throughout the
>    year.
>    There are so many points to be visited in Mahabaleshwar like Parsi
>    point, Elphinstone point, Wilson Point, Arthur seat point. There is
>    Vennna Lake where you can have boating and horse riding. Strawberry is
>    available at each and every place in Mahabaleshwar which is its main
>    attraction. There are so many hotels available but they are somewhat
>    costly. By the way it is the nice place to visit.
> 2. Mahabaleshwar is a best place for tourists. It is located in Maharashtra. I also visit Mahabaleshwar when I'm free time. It is
>    famous for their's natural beauty. Here is a one river ans when I
>    visit to Mahabaleshwar then I definitely go to ride on small boat, it
>    Is very joyful.

Need some suggestions on what algorithm can be used and about data processing approach. Links or tutorials are would be helpful too.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For your needs, you might want to look into a mix of sentiment analysis (to gauge experiences and cost opinions) and NER for extracting stuff like weather, places, and best visit times.

For sentiment analysis, simple tools like Python's TextBlob are super user-friendly. For NER, spaCy’s has some easy-to-follow guides and pre-trained models you can tweak to recognize specific entities in your reviews.

If you want a model to work with varied expressions and slang then try to play around with a model that efficiently works with zero-shot and few-shot learning. I recently found and integrated pretty interesting encoder-based text classification and NER [models](https://www.knowledgator.com/#models) into my data pipeline, and I only needed about 8-10 examples per label to train them on more complex cases. Moreover, encoder-based models are proficient in understanding the overall context of the text, which significantly increases the relevancy of the outputs.

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently reading Jurafsky and Martin's [Speech and Language Processing](https://web.stanford.edu/~jurafsky/slp3/) on NLP. I suggest you to take a look specifically at Chapter 17: *Information Extraction*. All models for this task are devoted to the extraction of lexico-syntactic patterns. They describe supervised, semi-supervised and unsupervised approaches.